# Import CSV to SQLite via shellscript, issues with primary key and duplicate data

Tags: sql, sqlite, shell, csv

I have two simple CSV files like this, both are very simple and in the same format:

```
NAME,NUMBER
abcd,1
qwerty,2
oiujkl,5
```

Many names in csv1 and csv2 are the same, but there are also names that only exist in csv1 or only in csv2. The numbers in csv1 and csv2, e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6... exist in both files, but in each file just once.

I want to import both files to one single SQLite db in the format "name,number-from-csv1,number-from-csv2". It sounds so simple, but I can't get it to work. In the end I want to get such a table:

```
NAME,NUMBER-FROM-CSV1,NUMBER-FROM-CSV2
abcd,1,1
qwerty,2,5
oiujkl,5,10
lkjsie,,99
wero,234,
```

I am missing the SQL logic :( I created the SQLite table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, number-from-csv1 INTEGER UNIQUE, number-from-csv2 INTEGER UNIQUE)
```

My shell script looks like this:

```
while IFS=',' read -r name number-from-csv1; do
    echo "INSERT INTO testdb (name, number-from-csv1) VALUES('$name', '$number-from-csv1');" 
done < file1.csv
```

I call this script like this: "./import.sh | sqlite3 asinfo.sqlite". This works fine for importing one file. If I just change "1" to "2" to import file2, it imports only the names that are not listed in file1. Then I tried to run this SQL-query:

```
UPDATE testdb SET number-from-csv2='$number-from-csv2' WHERE name='$name';
```

but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Consider uploading each file type into its own table.  Then use a join or a view to produce the table you want.

Upload the data from csv1 into a table called t1.  t1 has name and value columns.  Upload csv2 into t2.  t2 has columns name and value.

Now do something like

```
select t1.name, t1.value v1, t2.value v2
  from t1
  join t2 on t1.name = t2.name
 order by name;
```

You can create a view from this query.

Comment: Thanks Marvo! But this seems to work only for the names which exist in both csv files. The names that exist only in file1 or only in file2 are not in that view.

Comment: There are different kinds of "joins" in SQL.  It sounds like you want a "full outer join" (replace the word "join" with "full outer join" in the above query.)  This describes some different kinds of joins.  You can toy with them to get the result you need.
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Thanks, but there is no "full outer join" in SQLite. I found a way of using two LEFT JOIN together with an UNION to archive the same. This is working:

select csv1.name, csv1.csv1number, csv2.csv2number
  from csv1
  left outer join csv2 on csv1.name = csv2.name
UNION SELECT csv2.name, csv1.csv1number, csv2.csv2number from csv2 LEFT OUTER JOIN csv1 ON csv1.name = csv2.name;

Now I can import the files into two tables, issue this complicated query to export the data and import the new CSV again to a new SQLite db :) It works! But I have the feeling this is not the best option... :)